# Data mirroring suggestions

Tags: sql-server, replication, clustering, mirroring, storage

On my test environment, I have a SQL 2012 2-node physical cluster that accesses a common iSCSI storage on a separate Windows Server 2012 box. What options are there if I want to backup this storage to another storage array?

Also I want to mirror the DB to a DR site. Is log shipping ideal for this situation?

Thanks in advance,

Trev

Comment: In SQL Server 2012, database mirroring is deprecated. What ever DR solution you choose, it will depend on how much downtime is acceptable and how much you are willing to loose - [RTO and RPO](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-6-of-30-backups-understanding-rto-and-rpo/). What version of SQL Server are you using ?

Comment: @Kin Thanks for your reply. I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012. Our main site is connected via MPLS fiber link to the DR site. Pretty much it can handle Log Shipping traffic. One hour downtime is acceptable.